# Error while installing appium server

Tags: node.js, appium

I am trying to install appium server but i am getting the below error:
**"node" is not recognized as an internal or external command"**

> 1. I have installed node.js
> 2. Set the environment variables: NODE_HOME = C:\Program Files\nodejs

```
    Path = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

> 3. Entered the command **npm install -g appium**

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling node.js along with system re-boot and also as administrator, but the same error is repeated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can't install appium server like that on windows. 
Please download the appium desktop for windows from below link and then install :
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.5.0